# Are non-contentious hard forks a potential hindrance to the development and/or usage of the lightning network on top of Monero?

Tags: hard-fork, lightning-network, monero-second-tier

Let's say I open a private channel to someone today. After several years of using the channel I want to close it.
Would I be able to do it with a client that was in the meantime upgraded with a couple of non-contentious
forks?

I can't see how, but are such upgrades a risk to the so-called forced closures of channells?
Are soft forks, as a method of upgrading, more conducive to [composability of software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_composability_principle) when compared to non-contentious hardforks?